# (Swift) Trying to iterate through remaining elements in array, add those elements independently, and check to see if they match random number given

Tags: arrays, swift, while-loop, enumerate

Disclaimer: new to swift.

I have a simple dice game that needs to match the number shown on dice to the tiles(ints) remaining on the board. I am able to enumerate through the array for a direct match but, if the dice show a greater number than the tiles individually I need to check if those tiles(ints), in any combination, can also match the number on dice shown.

for loops, do-while, enumerations.....head is starting to explode. Example below shows a condensed version of where i think i'm going.  any help would be great.

var  array = [1,2,3,4]

func roundOver () {

```
var ran = Int(arc4random_uniform(7) % 7 + 1)

for (index,value)in enumerate(array) {
    if value == ran {
      println("match")
    } else if value != ran {
        do {..........huh?
```

Comment: Do you just want to find if the value exists in the array? You can use the `contains` or `find` built-in command to do that. Here's a list of built-in functions to accomplish stuff like that: http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/

Comment: thanks Graff for the quick reply. I am able to find the matching elements with find or contains. Thanks for the link as it is desperately needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to solve the ["Subset sum problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem):

> Given a set `S` and a number `x`, is there a subset of `S` whose sum is equal to `x`?

This problem can be efficiently solved with "dynamic programming", as described in
the Wikipedia article. For ***small sets***, a brute-force algorithm can be used which
simply tries all possible subsets. This can be recursively written as

```
func isSummableTo(array: [UInt], _ value: UInt) -> Bool {
    if value == 0 {
        // We have reached the exact sum
        return true
    } else if array.count == 0 {
        // No elements left to try
        return false
    }
    // Split into first element and remaining array:
    var array1 = array
    let first = array1.removeAtIndex(0)
    // Try to build the sum without or with the first element:
    return isSummableTo(array1, value) || (value >= first && isSummableTo(array1, value - first))
}
```

(Here I have assumed that you work only with non-negative integers.)

For example

```
isSummableTo([1, 3, 5, 10], 6) == true
```

because 1 + 5 = 6, and

```
isSummableTo([1, 3, 5, 10], 7) == false
```

because there is not subset of the numbers 1, 3, 5, 10 that sums up to 7.

Comment: Martin....... You saved me 40 more agonizing hours of staring at a computer screen. With a simple tweak (thanks to the new Xcode upgrade) it works just great. I continue to realize how much I don't know. Thanks for the link as well as i will spend the next few days trying to wrap my brain around it.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to record the successful subset in this case? I tried to append first in successful cases but get duplicates.